# AJAX and Rails: Parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an AJAX call to my rails API that only renders JSON and I keep getting a parsererror. I tried various things but nothing works.

Here is my **ajax call**

```
$.ajax('/api/users/show/:id', {
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: {
    id: 1
  },
  success: function(response) {
    return alert("Hey");
  },
  complete: function(response, textStatus) {
    console.log(response);
    return alert("Hey: " + textStatus);
  }
});
```

Here is my API method

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def show
        render :json => User.find(params[:id])
    end   

end
```

It seems like I am doing everything correct. I properly output JSON from the server, and I state in the AJAX call that I take JSON as expected input. Also, the AJAX call properly hits the server because I can see it in the server logs and it outputs a `200` status.

The problem is the AJAX call never runs success so I cant properly access the response variable I need.

Comment: what is the error? Also, the URL you're hitting doesn't look right. You really have `show/:id` in it?

Comment: statusText outputs `parsererror`

Answer (score 2):

When you specify `dataType: 'json'`. The returned data is already a javascript object. You should not parse it again using `JSON.parse`. Jquery will automatically parse the string from server before passing it to your `success` function. In your case, it could be that the JSON string from the server is not valid and jquery has error while parsing it and does not call your `success` function

Comment: Sorry I left that there on accident. Even after removing that I get the same `parsererror`

Comment: @user2158382: well then you need to check if the json string from the server is well-formed. As I said, jquery will parse it before passing to the success function. If there is any error when parsing, jquery may not call your success function